# How to build a cheap (but safe) laser engraver with spare parts

Tags: printer-building, laser

I would love to start a small engraving business without having to purchase expensive hardware.

Using scrap parts at home, or parts from broken CD players, are there any ways to make a laser engraver at home? My cousin managed to make one of his own from scraps.

Comment: How cheap, what area, engraving what material?

Comment: There are ways to do one or several at home (I made one), try to look for laser forums.

Comment: I don't know anything about laser engravers, but you might find these links useful: [Make your own 3D printer for under \$60 using Components with Instructables Design](https://3dprint.com/23080/instructables-build-3d-printer/) and 
[Instructables – EWaste 60$ 3DPrinter by mikelllc in 3D-Printing](http://www.instructables.com/id/eWaste-60-3DPrinter/?ALLSTEPS)

Comment: This question is very opinion based, it's also asking for 'competent person' advice in terms of safety. If you want safe, pay someone who has insurance. Thinking a bit more about this question (and adding my downvote), I think it needs to be split into a few parts. Clearly a laser engraver _can_ be built from scrap, what is easier to answer in the context of this site is some details about 'is a CD player laser strong enough to engrave', what safety do I need with a CD laser (or other type if you go that way). The business aspect of using DIY hardware I think is way off topic.

Comment: "cheapest" is a pretty much impossible to answer question. One might arguably get it rather cheap if one converts a printer ot an engraver... This might best be a host for Laser-cutter questions interlinked or a general design consideration question. Basically there is a design triangle of "Cost-Safety-Versatility" to cover here: to go into one direction of this design triangle means to sacrifice in the other two, to to a compromise of two of these means to sacrifice in the third: there is no "Cheap-safe-AND-Versatile" machine.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you do not have knowledge about the electronics then consider buying a cheap etching machine instead.

## Build

Take a look on https://hackaday.com/ and search for laser engravers.

I have found following articles in few seconds:

- [Hackaday.com: DVD LASER DIODE USED TO BUILD A LASER ENGRAVER](https://hackaday.com/2013/05/06/dvd-laser-diode-used-to-build-a-laser-engraver/)
- [Hackaday.com: LASER PCB EXPOSER BUILT FROM CD-ROM DRIVES](https://hackaday.com/2016/03/14/laser-pcb-exposer-built-from-cd-rom-drives/)
- [Hackaday.com: HOMEBUILT LASER ENGRAVER USING SALVAGED PARTS](https://hackaday.com/2017/10/31/homebuilt-laser-engraver-using-salvaged-parts/)
- [Hackaday.com: ENTRY-LEVEL 3D PRINTER BECOMES BUDGET PCB MACHINE](https://hackaday.com/2017/11/27/entry-level-3d-printer-becomes-budget-pcb-machine/)

## Cheap laser engravers

And this one is about 2018 list of laser cutters/engravers: [15 Best Laser Cutters, Laser Engravers & AIO Machines of 2018](https://all3dp.com/1/best-home-desktop-laser-cutter-engraver-aio-machine/%20It%20lists%20machines%20around%20100$). It lists machines around 100$

- Meterk Laser Engraver ($125)
- NEJE DK-8-KZ ($70)
- QIILU Mini Laser Engraver ($130)
- SuperCarver K2 ($160)

## Safety

Laser could damage your eyes (imagine laser reflection or if the machine falls from table when it's working). Take a look on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_safety).

The best option is to use *acrylic cover* in same color as your laser, so you can observe the etching process and the laser beam is always blocked. For example take a look on orange cover of [Formlabs Form 2](https://formlabs.com/3d-printers/form-2/) 3d printer (it uses laser for printing).

Another protection is to wear *laser protection glasses*. Again the glasses must have same color as your laser.

Using laser for cutting or engraving means to burn material away. You should have good ventilation in the room.

Buy a *smoke detector* if you use cheap electronics with higher power consumption.

Comment: This is a *mostly* link only answer. If the links die, which they usually do, then the answer will be not much use. Please edit and include a summary of each link, and the highlights

Comment: As an alternative to editing this, you can always delete it to earn the 'peer-pressure' badge. I think it's important to address the safety issues if you do answer this question. To clarify - not my downvotes (hadn't voted on the question till now)

Comment: @SeanHoulihane thanks for the critics. I rather try to improve the answer then just to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a printer and a diode laser head which will etch aluminum for under $4k, but you're going to have to manage potentially noxious fumes based on what material you're lasering. It's safe if used safely: the focal distance is 15-20mm from the lens, but all present should wear PPE.

Note: I work for Hyrel3D.